Function is not getting call from html
Below is simple html code, am trying to call function , bt its not getting fire ,,, is anyone know..
 <div (click)="openPreview(modelvalue)">
     <i class="icon-image-fui"></i>
     {{modelvalue}}
  </div>
  <label (click)="donwload(modelvalue)">Download</label>

didnt apply any css class,,, usually should not happen



// You will need to define modelValue somewhere in your script.
var modelValue = 'Your Model Value Here';

function openPreview(value) {
  alert("Preview: " + value);
}

function download(value) {
  alert("Download: " + value);
}

// Set the display value
document.getElementById('modelValueDisplay').textContent = modelValue;
<div id="preview" onclick="openPreview(modelValue)">
  <i class="icon-image-fui"></i>
  <span id="modelValueDisplay"></span>
</div>
<label id="download" onclick="download(modelValue)">Download</label>



you're trying to use Angular syntax in plain HTML Angular uses (click) to bind click events in its templates which will not work if you are not actually using Angular or if Angular is not properly set up in your project.
